# How to add msnry.reloadItems() to vanilla JS script

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll, masonry

I am very new in js, javascript, ajax, etc., I am using php and build only wordpress sites. Today I trying make to my site the hybrid pagination, what someone call it the "HolyScroll or Holy Scroll", the target this:
http://scrollsample.appspot.com/items

So I working on the infinite-scroll.com with Desandro's Masonry and my code now it looks like this (I did this in the last 5 hours...):

```
var grid = document.querySelector('.container');
var msnry;

imagesLoaded( grid, function() {
  // init Isotope after all images have loaded
  msnry = new Masonry( grid, {
    itemSelector: '.item'
  });
});

// -----------

var elem = document.querySelector('.container');
var infScroll = new InfiniteScroll( elem, {
  // options
  path: 'page/{{#}}/',
  append: '.item',
  history: 'push',
  historyTitle: true,
  prefill: true,
// load pages on init until user can scroll
scrollThreshold: 1000,
// trigger scrollThreshold event when viewport is <100px from bottom of scroll area
status: '.page-load-status',
});

// element argument can be a selector string
//   for an individual element
var infScroll = new InfiniteScroll( '.container', {
  // options
});
```

So finally works the infinite scroll, the history, the masonry (only on the first call) and the imagesLoaded, And now need paste to this the reloadItems option, but dont working...
Here is the guide: https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#reloaditems

Please, someone could help me? I can not find a simple tutorial to this with Vanilla JS, in turn the JQuery versions not working for me...

*Unfortunately MarkovskI drew my attention not everyone can click on a link, so I copy here, what Desandro write on his site:

"For frameworks like Angular and React, reloadItems may be useful to apply changes to the DOM to Masonry."

```
 // vanilla JS
 msnry.reloadItems()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the "Holy Scroll", the hybrid, ajax / js loaded infinite scroll WITH pagination, what search engines loves, so this totally user and SEO friendly:

Source sites:
https://infinite-scroll.com/
https://masonry.desandro.com/
https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

So, I just now learning php, I am only webdesigner and after I realized, the ALL wordpress plugins what promises you "infinite scroll" (like Ajax Load More, Ajax Pagination & infinite Scroll, DMD Infinite Scroll, Jetpack, YITH Infinite Scroll and etc.) rip-off and KILL YOUR ALL SEO if you using these plugins without LICENSE, I started looking the solution on the net. The first what it comes face to face the Google' Webmaster Central Blog:
https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly.html

So after this article I knew what I wanted, but by the time, what I found it the keywords (thus: the browser history about infinite scroll) and the simple fact, that now need building my masonry layout (because up to now I using the Ajax Load More plugin, and this did it the masonry to me), so I never learning JS... I worked on this in the last ~35 hours, but you can instantly learn to do it yourself, as you read it all along. (The long introductory serving the keywords, to find you here too.)

So, you can modify your infinite scroll options off this official guide:
https://infinite-scroll.com/options.html
The VERY IMPORTANT THING, WHAT NEED FOR YOU, IS THIS:
https://infinite-scroll.com/options.html#history

So, put these links (or follow these steps: https://infinite-scroll.com/#install) to your footer (Or header, but Google recommend that call .js and .css files in footer, thus reduce it you pageload.):
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/infinite-scroll@3/dist/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>`

And here is so the full "Holy Scroll" code with masonry layout what using images Loaded (imagesLoaded), so never more overlapping your images.
**Just Put This code to your footer between:** `<script></script>`

```
  var grid = document.querySelector('.container');
  var msnry = new Masonry( grid, {
    itemSelector: '.youritem', // select none at first
  });

  // initial items reveal
  imagesLoaded( grid, function() {
    msnry.options.itemSelector = '.youritem';
    var items = grid.querySelectorAll('.youritem');
    msnry.reloadItems( items ); // This reload the masonry layout after the first call
    msnry.layout(); // This restrain the overlapping on the first call
  });

  //-------------------------------------//
  // init Infinte Scroll

  var infScroll = new InfiniteScroll( grid, {
    // options
    path: 'page/{{#}}/', // YOUR PAGINATION STRUCTURE !!!IMPORTANT!!! REPLACE IT
    append: '.youritem',
    history: 'push',
    historyTitle: true,
    prefill: true,
  // load pages on init until user can scroll
  scrollThreshold: 1000,
  // trigger scrollThreshold event when viewport is <100px from bottom of scroll area
// (I using 1000, that my users never have to wait for the loading of the next page...
// The calling it will start to working, before the screen shows the bottom of the page...)
  status: '.page-load-status',
  outlayer: msnry,
  });
```

Okay, so replace it the `.container` to YOUR site container what includes the items (items = posts, images, anything) and replace it the `.youritem` to your grid item (so the div what include ONE item)!
Very important, that you replace the value of the path: to your pagination structure, where the current page's number is **{{#}}**! (So if your site works thus: **yourdomain.com/page/2/** your path value is: **'page/{{#}}/'**)

Finally you make your design with .css (Included the masonry parameters (width, etc.)!)